# Как в Unity получить компонент через переменную типа string?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю шахматы и столкнулся с проблемой: не могу получить компонент через переменную типа `string`.

Есть *6* классов: Pawn, King и т.д. Надо обратиться к этому классу через переменную, т.к. каждый раз фигура, а, значит и класс, разный.

Запись ниже не срабатывает

```
Canvas.GetComponent<Global_Variables().Active_Figure.GetComponent(Script).Cancel()
```

Пишет:

> *Component* не содержит определения для *Cancel*.

Подскажите, что делать?

Comment: Ничего непонятно. кто такие Pawn и King?  к чему они относятся? Причем тут Canvas? фигура каждый раз разная и что с того? напиши лучше подробнее, покажи код. что и куда ты пытаешься там воткнуть. скорее всего тебе нужно использовать полиморфизм. но по сумбурному описанию мало что можно ответить

Comment: Прочти еще раз и поймешь. Я делаю шахматы. У меня есть объект- клетка, которая принимает в себя выбранную игроком фигуру. Скрипт, который висит на фигуре зависит от ее названия: на пешке висит скрипт **Pawn**, на короле **King**. В скрипте клетки я должен вызывать определенные функции фигур. Сделать это можно через `Canvas.GetComponent<Global_Variables().Active_Figure.GetComponent` а вот далее я не знаю, как. Мне нужно указывать имя скрипта, который висит на фигуре, а через переменную типа **string** не выходит. Вот и зашел сюда, чтобы выяснить, как это можно сделать

Comment: GetComponent<System.Type> подразумевает обращение к компоненте определенного типа. А ты обращаешься к экземпляру какого обьекта/класса и пытаешься вызвать там функцию. Если тебе надо вызвать функцию на фигуре, и для каждой фигуры эта функция одинаковая используй на классах фигур - родительский класс. Если нужна одинаковое только название и кол-во параметров функции, добро пожаловать к интерфейсам. Например, 'interface iFigure{ void func();}' наследуешь классами king и т.д Затем getComponent<iFigure>().func();   Если совсем тупо, юзай SendMessage(string nameFunc);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как я писал в самом первом комментарии: используй полиморфизм, наследование и прочие прелести ООП.

Один из вариантов: создай базовый класс для фигур, которые будут от него наследоваться. А далее ты можешь брать компонент так:

```
GetComponent<БАЗОВОЕ_ИМЯ_КЛАССА>()
```

если быть точнее то:

```
Canvas.GetComponent<Global_Variables>().Active_Figure.GetComponent<БАЗОВОЕ_ИМЯ_КЛАССА>
```

и вызывать метод.

---

**Тестовый пример.**

Родитель фигур:

```
public abstract class FigureParent : MonoBehaviour {    
    public virtual void Cancel() {
        Debug.Log("cancel method from " + this);
    }
}
```

фигура 1

```
public class Pawn : FigureParent {
    public override void Cancel() {
        base.Cancel();
        Debug.Log("action from Pawn");
    }
}
```

фигура 2

```
public class King : FigureParent {
    public override void Cancel() {
        base.Cancel();
        Debug.Log("action from King");
    }
}
```

Далее скрипт, в котором, предположительно, два объекта, содержащие эти скрипты:

```
public class TestFigure : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject fig1;
    public GameObject fig2;

    void Start () {
        fig1.GetComponent<FigureParent>().Cancel();
        fig2.GetComponent<FigureParent>().Cancel();
    }   
}
```

В результате этого примера на консоль выведется:

```
cancel method from Pawn (Pawn)
action from Pawn
cancel method from King (King)
action from King
```

---

В целом тебе нужно почитать про наследование, полиморфизм, абстрактные классы/методы, интерфейсы и всё, с помощью чего можно объединить классы с одинаковым функционалом и не только...В общем, основы :)

Comment: Хорошо. Прочту. Спасибо)

Comment: @GeorgeTuzikov в целом, не зная точно, что у тебя написано в классах - либо сейчас наследуй их от общего предка, а в `GetComponent` указывай его имя...либо делай интерфейс  в каждом классе реализуй его методы и в `GetComponent` указывай уже имя интерфейса. Должно работать без проблем

Comment: Создал родительский класс **Figure**. Унаследовал остальные фигуры от него. Все равно `GetComponent<Figure>` не работает- не видит он **Figure**, хотя **Figure** public.

Comment: Понятно, решил. Юнити протупил и не увидел родительский класс **Figure**- **MonoBehaviour**. Пересоздание скрипта решило проблему. Все работает. Всем спасибо!

Comment: @GeorgeTuzikov `не увидел родительский класс Figure- MonoBehaviour` - ага. а я специально пример нарисовал, чтоб на словах не объяснять)) Ну если чего - можешь галку ставить) Не забудь книги почитать))